# find all possible matches using regex python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

How can I find all possible matches using regex in python and not just the first match that appear?

For example -

```
import re
text = '1234'
re.findall(r'\d{2}',text)
```

will return -

```
['12', '34']
```

However I want all the groups i.e. -

```
['12', '23', '34']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions consume characters and don't go back over previous matches. A way around this is to use zero-length assertions (see code below) to capture what you want. I'm sure there's a more pythonic way of accomplishing this, but using regex alone, you can use this.

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/AZnBrJ/1)

```
(?=(\d{2}))
```

Results are in capture group 1:

- `12`
- `23`
- `34`

### Explanation

- `(?=(\d{2}))` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

  - `(\d{2})` Capture your original expression into capture group 1